# wp_insert_post() or similar for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

Need to insert custom post type objects from code. Haven't been able to add using the default method

```
$id = wp_insert_post(array('post_title'=>'random', 'post_type'=>'custom_post'));
```

creates a regular post instead.

Comment: Have you registered a `custom post type` named as `custom_post` before using this call?

Comment: yes its registered

Comment: never mind, its working, there was a minor bug in the file, this exact snippet is correct. just replace 'custom_post' with post type of your choosing!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Example):

> [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Example) will fill out a default list of these but the
>   user is required to provide the title and content otherwise the
>   database write will fail.

```
$id = wp_insert_post(array(
  'post_title'=>'random', 
  'post_type'=>'custom_post', 
  'post_content'=>'demo text'
));
```

Answer (score 19):

It can be done using the following code :-

**To enter a new post for a custom type**

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
   'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
   'post_title' => $your_title,
   'post_content' => $your_content,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'comment_status' => 'closed',   // if you prefer
   'ping_status' => 'closed',      // if you prefer
));
```

After inserting the post, a post id will be returned by the above function. Now if you want to enter any post meta information w.r.t this post then following code snippet can be used.

```
if ($post_id) {
   // insert post meta
   add_post_meta($post_id, '_your_custom_1', $custom1);
   add_post_meta($post_id, '_your_custom_2', $custom2);
   add_post_meta($post_id, '_your_custom_3', $custom3);
}
```

Comment: The 'meta_input' parameter can be used in the 'wp_insert_post' array, to add meta fields, instead of using 'add_post_meta' afterward.

Comment: Thanks for the post. @AncientRow, can you provide an example including `meta_input`?

Answer (score 4):

This example worked for me using meta_input

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
   'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
   'post_title' => $your_title,
   'post_content' => $your_content,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'comment_status' => 'closed',
   'ping_status' => 'closed',
   'meta_input' => array(
      '_your_custom_1' => $custom_1,
      '_your_custom_2' => $custom_2,
      '_your_custom_3' => $custom_3,
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found using `isset()` allowed me to use `wp_insert_post()` on custom post types:

```
if ( !isset( $id ) ) { 
    $id = wp_insert_post( $new, true ); 
}
```

Comment: To properly format code in your answer (or question), highlight it and click **{}** above the edit box.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried every solution provided in most of the forums. But the actual solution that worked for me was the post type was the length of post_type.
The post_type length is limited to 20 characters. So anyone who has a similar issue try this if anything else didn't work.