# Store user form submitted information in post type

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, forms

I'm building an internal peoples directory using wp for a client. I'm styling the search form and the search result page that are working fine. I need some help to understand what's the better approach to save the user submitted data, I got a form that will hold four fields and a modal popup that will show a map that locate the user and to store the lat and lng info. Someone suggested me to use a custom post type to do this, but I'm not sure about, this because the information will be accessibile by users only by doing a search, and the link to every page will be a map that will display a marker at the lat and lng stored.
Can someone help me to reach my goal?

Here is my data sumbission form that will be in a dedicated page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 shadow-lg" style="padding:1em;">
      <form method="POST" action="">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label><?php _e('First Name'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="Nome">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label><?php _e('Last name'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="Cognome">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label><?php _e('N'); ?></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="" name="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label><?php _e('M'); ?></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="" name="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label><?php _e('Position'); ?></label>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="" href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><?php _e('Add'); ?></button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><?php _e('Cancel'); ?></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I didn't write the logics when the form is submitted, I want to use ajax, but not sure about, this because I need to lock the submit button until a position is registered.

Comment: Are these internal people already Wordpress users in the database? Do they send the data themselves or any other user? Is a login required if they send it themselves?

Comment: no, they arent registered and I don't need to register them for login or similar. I just need to collect the info and then save them, to make the people inserted searchable from wp search

Comment: I asked because you could use the usermeta to extend the user infos. Like this it will be a good idea to use a custom post type. So one can edit the persons in the backend if needed. In the custom search you can limit the results to the CPT as well. You can use AJAX with the REST API and a custom endpoint, which will do all the required things you need.

Comment: Tge problem with the CPT is that I can use the title field to assign the first name and the last name field, but for the other two that are date and for the collected position (latitude,longitude), I don't know where to store them, the content field of the cpt isn't the best way. Using the cpt I also can create a template to display the data but this will collide with the information stored? @moped can you provide an example of storing in a cpt?

Comment: You can create your own backend layout for your CPT. You are not bound to the default blocks or fields you see when you create a post. Use the action ```add_meta_boxes``` like here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/ after you registered your CPT. In the callback you can build your own fields and save them with the ```save_post``` action.

Comment: @moped I've found this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106973/wp-insert-post-or-similar-for-custom-post-type and I think that this is what I will do to save the submitted form data. In the answer there is a snippet that will call a function to add custom post meta, I will assign the latitude, longitude and the other two fields in this way